# Typescript narrowing doesn't work when function is always throwing

Tags: typescript

I have a utility function which I use for throwing different kinds of errors in an organized way. It always throws an error. However, Typescript is not smart enough to use this for narrowing:

```ts
interface A {
  x: {
    a?: string;
  }
}

const g = (s: A): string => {
  if (!s.x.a) {
    throw Error("mess");
  }
  return s.x.a // compiles just fine
}

const f = (): never => {
  throw Error('message');
}

const gg = (s: A): string => {
  if (!s.x.a) {
    f()
  }
  return s.x.a // ERROR: can be undefined!
}
```

I thought returning `never` will help the compiler to be smarter, but it doesn't. Is there another way or a keyword to use to achieve this?

Comment: `never` doesn't actually have any affect. It's just a marker indicating that this function should never return, similar to how `void` lets you know that the return value doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: You can use `asserts` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzP83N) to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @caTS you should post an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @caTS I tried to push it a bit further and make an always asserting function with something like "asserts false" or similar, but it didn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really have `f` magically make whatever condition it was called under the assertion condition, but if you pass that condition directly to `f` and utilize `asserts`, then you will come up with something that is similar to the built-in `asserts` function from Node.js:

```
function f(thing: any): asserts thing {
  if (!thing) throw Error('message');
}
```

Pretty uncanny resemblance with the real deal:

```
function assert(condition: any, msg?: string): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new AssertionError(msg);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx8XKm)

Answer (score 1):

why not just return f as you know it would throw anyways and halt the execution

```
const gg = (s: A): string => {
  if (!s.x.a) {
    return f()
  }
  return s.x.a // ERROR: can be undefined!
}
```

Comment: In practice, that's what I ended up doing, I just asked the question to learn about some language features that I didn't know about. And I learned! :)